# Why does the infinite iteration of $f(x)={a\over x}+1$ approach ${\sqrt{4a+1}+1\over 2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, dynamical-systems

First, define $f^{(n)}{(x)}$ as the nth iterate of x. So, $f^{(0)}(x)=x$, $f^{(1)}(x)=f(x)$, $f^{(2)}(x)=f(f(x))$, and so on.

In this specific case, where $f(x)={a\over x}+1$, if you set $a=1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}f^{(n)}{(x)} = {1+\sqrt5 \over2}$ (the golden ratio) for all positive $x$.

I noticed that for all x, including non-integer values of x, $\lim_{n \to \infty}f^{(n)}{(x)}$ will always equal ${\sqrt{4a+1}+1 \over 2}$. I found it interesting how this always seems to occur, but I am not sure why such a nice formula would come out.

This is just out of interest, and any responses would be greatly appreciated!

Note:
I tested this using Desmos, and after about 100 iterations the values seem to match up to 11 decimal points, the highest that Desmos shows.

Comment: In general there ar two possibilities: the sequence converges to a fixed point of $f$, or it diverges. Now, to find the limit, you have to solve $$f(x)=x$$ In your case, this leads to a quadratic equation.

Comment: A necessary condition is that x = f(x).  In this case, that yields a quadratic equation, which gives you two solutions.  However, a further necessary condition is that a solution is stable.  In this case, I suspect that one of the roots of the quadratic is stable and the other is not, though I haven't checked this.

Comment: Have you tried it for $a<0$?

Comment: Desmos seemed to think it also converged to the same value, but I didn't trust it, because when I plugged in 0 it also gave the value, even though 0 should cause it to be undefined after the first iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any such iterated sequence where $f$ is continuous, any possible limit point $\ell$ must satisfy
$$
\ell = f(\ell) \tag{1}
$$
since you have $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ and (as $f$ is continuous) $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \ell$ implies
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1} = f(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n)\,.
$$
((1) is thus a necessary condition)

Now, in your specific case solving
$$
\ell = \frac{a}{\ell}+1 \tag{2}
$$
or equivalently $\ell^2 - \ell - a = 0$ (for $\ell \neq 0$) yields
$$
\ell = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}\,. \tag{3}
$$

Comment: Might also be worth computing $f'$ at those values.

Comment: (Now, also note that for a positive initial value   $x_0$, and $a>0$ then the sequence $(x_n)_n$ will obviously stay positive, so it's pretty unlikely it could converge to $\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$...)

Comment: @MarkMcClure It would to check whether a sequence would actually converge to such a point (i.e., are they attractors). My answer adresses the necessary condition a limit must satisfy, not whether the sequence will actually converge to it.